# How to update JSONB column with value coming from another table column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a source table, which lists like below:

public.source

```
Id | part_no | category
1 | 01270-4 | Landscape
2 | 01102-3 | Sports
```

Then, I have target table with jsonb column (combinations) , which list like below;

public.target

```
Id | part_no | combinations
7 | 01270-4 | {"subject":""}
8 | 01102-3 | {"subject":""}
```

My problem is - how I can update the target table with jsonb column (combinations) with the values coming from source table using the part_no column?
Output like:

```
Id | part_no | combinations
7 | 01270-4 | {"subject":"Landscape"}
8 | 01102-3 | {"subject":"Sports"}
```

I tried below but giving error:

```
UPDATE public.target t
SET combinations = jsonb_set(combinations,'{subject}','s.category',false)
FROM public.source s
WHERE s.part_no = t.part_no;
```

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 2: SET combinations = jsonb_set(combinations,'{subject}', 's.categor...
^
DETAIL:  Token "s" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: s...
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 77

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `to_jsonb` function to convert `s.category` to JSON

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=513496ed5efdca138fd53fd7def628b7)

```sql
UPDATE public.target t
SET combinations = jsonb_set(combinations,'{subject}',to_jsonb(s.category),false)
FROM public.source s
WHERE s.part_no = t.part_no
```

Or you can use sample structure for join and update two JSON field:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f94f827bd6a418900fe818e0ae19932a)

```sql
UPDATE public.target t
SET combinations = combinations || jsonb_build_object('subject', s.category)
FROM public.source s
WHERE s.part_no = t.part_no
```

Comment: Perfect!  THANK YOU very  much Pooya.  You're the man!

Comment: Word of caution, if the value in `s.category` is `null` this will ignore the path and set the value to `null` deleting your entire json object. You can get around this by using `jsonb_set_lax`.

Comment: Some helpful info related to my comment above: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/jsonb_set_lax/