# Postgres: Update jsonb from other table column which is encrypted

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am migrating a data from an encrypted jsonb column (`app_id` field) in a table to another jsonb column in a different table.

As said: origin table column is encrypted. Destination one is not.

Right now I have the following query:

```
UPDATE destination d 
SET payload = jsonb_set(payload,'{app_id}', to_jsonb('the_origin.app_id'), true)
FROM 
    (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(d.payload::bytea, 'the-decrypt-pass')::json->>'app_id'::text), ',') as app_id 
        FROM origin 
        WHERE id='origin_id'
    ) as the_origin
WHERE d.id='destination_id';
```

Error response is:

> SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257726/could-not-determine-polymorphic-type-because-input-has-type-unknown) I have used the `array_to_string(array_agg` "hack", but this is still not working.

EDIT:
as suspected it is not related (yet) to the encrypt column, the following query with a non encrypted `value` gets the same error response

```
UPDATE destination d 
SET payload = jsonb_set(payload,'{o.value}', to_jsonb('origin.destination_value'), true)
FROM origin o
WHERE d.origin_id=o.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [previous link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257726/could-not-determine-polymorphic-type-because-input-has-type-unknown) and from this question: [How to update JSONB column with value coming from another table column in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69991860/844451) . Following query is fully working:

```
UPDATE destination d 
SET payload = payload || jsonb_build_object('app_id', the_origin.app_id)
FROM 
    (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(d.payload::bytea, 'the-decrypt-pass')::json->>'app_id'::text), ',') as app_id 
        FROM origin 
        WHERE id='origin_id'
    ) as the_origin
WHERE d.id='destination_id';
```